# Frame rate in a simple Flappy Bird game is accelerating Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm working on a simple Flappy Bird game on my macOS 10.14.2. The problem is that while playing the game it executes more and more frames each second starting from 120 up, even though `print(display.fps)` stubbornly shows 30.

```
local birdImage = display.newImage("resources/BirdMiddle.png")

local gravity = 0.8

bird = {x = 0.5 * display.contentWidth, y = 0.5 * display.contentHeight, body = birdImage, verVel = 0}

function bird:enterFrame()
    bird.verVel = bird.verVel + gravity
    bird.y = bird.y + bird.verVel

    local t = os.date( '*t' )
    print( os.time( t ) )

    bird.body.y = bird.y
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", bird)
```

Here's the code, but I think that the problem is caused by my laptop, because Corona warned me, after installation, that it may not work properly on mac newer than 10.2

When I run it, `print` writes the time 120 times, then 250 times in the next frame and so on. What can I do?

EDIT

I don't know what was wrong, but I changed gravity into physics module, and now it works fine

Comment: How can we help you? We need code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I've added the code, but I wonder whether this is my coding issue or hardware...